# Download file from URL in Python

Tags: python-3.x, jsp, download

I am logged in in a page and I use a bookmark to download a CSV file. I just click on the link and after some seconds, the file gets downloaded in my PC. I am now trying to automate the "downloading file" process from the URL in Python.

The URL that triggers a file download is the following:

**`app.example.com/export/org.jsp?media=yes&csv=yes`**

What I tried in Python3 is shown below:

```
##First way
import requests

payload = {'inUserName': 'test.test@test.com','inUserPass': 'test'}

with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post('https://app.example.com/', data=payload)
    #print(p.text)
    r = s.get('https://app.example.com/export/org.jsp?media=yes&csv=yes')

###Second way
import urllib
import requests

payload = {'inUserName': 'test.test@test.com', 'inUserPass': 'test'}
url = 'https://app.example.com/'
requests.post(url, data=payload)

###Third way
import urllib.request

with urllib.request.urlopen("http://app.example.com/export/org.jsp?media=yes&csv=yes") as url:
    s = url.read()
#print(s)
```

I want to avoid the page scraping technique where I will login in the page and then visit the url. The platform used does not have an API where I can request the file in a different way.